# Streamlabs API Access to other users not working

Tags: api, oauth

I could successfully generate the access token using the following code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Session["Resp"]!=null)
        {
            LBL2.Text=Session["Resp"].ToString();
            return;
        }
        int c=0;
        try
        {
            if (Session["Counter"] == null)
                Session.Add("Counter", 0);
            else{
                c = int.Parse(Session["Counter"].ToString()) + 1;
            }
            lbl1.Text = c.ToString();
            string CD = Request.QueryString["CODE"].ToString();
            code.Value = CD;
            form1.Method = "POST";
            //form1.Action = "https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/token";
            form1.Action = "https://streamlabs.com/api/v2.0/token";


            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                        | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

                byte[] response =
                client.UploadValues("https://streamlabs.com/api/v2.0/token", new NameValueCollection()
               {
                   { "client_id", client_id.Value },
                   { "client_secret", client_secret.Value },
                   { "redirect_uri", redirect_uri.Value },
                   { "code", CD },
                   { "grant_type", grant_type.Value },
               });

                string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
                token deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<token>(result);
                LBL2.Text = result;
                tok.Text = deserializedProduct.access_token;
            }

                
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
        }
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();  
    }
```

HOWEVER, I Could not POST a donation using the access token. The SAME THING HAS WORKED AND STILL WORKING with the previous version of Streamlabs API, but I could not make this version work. They have recently updated to API version 2.0.
It is displaying "Error 401 Unauthorized"

Donation: I am hard-coding the Access token and the Data part currently..

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                    | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

            client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer J1Zi7M7c6dqGyQb4DGnW2U9yqdREgP5dJ94Ya4CM");
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            client.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            string response = client.UploadString("https://streamlabs.com/api/v2.0/donations","POST", "{\"skip_alert\":\"no\",\"name\":\"Joy\",\"identifier\":\"joyganguly@gmail.com\",\"amount\":254,\"currency\":\"USD\"}"); // retJson2(txtName.Text, decimal.Parse(txtAmt.Text)));
            string result = response;   
            RetData2 deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetData2>(result);
            Lbl1.Text = deserializedProduct.donation_id;

        }
    }
```

i have described my issue , kindly help. I am trying to figure it out from days but no success.
Thanks.

Comment: What does this line do? `client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;`

Comment: Hi, should you be posting your bearer token like this on stackoverflow? Does it expire?

Comment: Hi Michal , that line is of no use, I thought I am having issue with creds, so I used it, but it gives the same error even when I delete that line.

Comment: Hi Jose, yes, the same thing has worked in API V1.0, it does not expire , as documented by them.

Comment: Thanks to all. The application is working. It was pending for approval only. And in the previous version we don't have to wait until approval. It worked as soon as we created it. Sorry for any inconvinience. Thanks a lot.